# Array sorting input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i requer help with the array sorting input. so the story is next i am making a code to input the vote number of the candidates ( there are 5 of them) and output the amount of wotes for each candidate. also it need to terminate when the -1 is entered. i have figured all the sorting and swaping functions and have problems with actual input code. what i have so far is not right but it might give you an idea.

```
import java.util.*;

public class VoteCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create empty array
        int[] votes = new int[5];

        //input data
        input(votes);

    }

    public static void input(int[] votes) 
    {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
        int votecount = kybd.nextInt();

        while (votecount !=-1) 
        {
            votes[votecount]++;  
            System.out.println("Candidate" + votes +"Has" +votecount + "votes");        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `votecount = kybd.nextInt();` You need to do that inside the loop also at the end. Also do `votes[index++] = votecount` instead of `votes[votecount]++;`.

Comment: What should the output look like?  candidate-no = number of votes sorted by number of votes

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have created an infinite loop reason being that `votecount` will never be equal to  -1 since you are never changing it inside the loop.

What you need to do is to move the code where you ask and record the vote within the loop. But before doing `votes[votecount]++` check to make sure that the user did not input `-1` since this will cause an `ArrayOutofBoundsException`. So you can loop for ever and when the user enters -1 you can `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VoteCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create empty array
        int[] votes = new int[5];
        //initialise with 0
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            votes[i] = 0;
        }

        //input data
        input(votes);

    }

    public static void input(int[] votes) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int votecount = kybd.nextInt();
        while (votecount !=-1) {
            votes[votecount]++;  
            System.out.println("Candidate " + votecount +" Has " +votes[votecount] + " votes");
            System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
            votecount = kybd.nextInt();
        }

    }
}
```

Now you have to add the functionality that the user is not allowed to enter anything above 4 and below -1, otherwise you will get an exception. Good luck!

Comment: This seems to be like homework... if this is the case, throwing code at the OP will not make him learn. Also, when the user enters -1 your code will throw an ArrayOutofBoundsException.

Comment: Forgot to ask the user to enter the number of the candidate to vote for. As it is, the user will have a blank console... which might cause confusion.

Comment: yup just saw that thanks... now its pretty much done... and he will learn it I'm sure ;)

Comment: Yours is wery close and it is just what i need only after enterin - 1 i need to see a list of 5 candidates ( no names yet as the 2nd aray was not set) and the amount of votes for each
candidate 1 - has 2 votes
 
can 2 - has 4 votes

etc. etc.
could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read from the console and fill up the `votes` array:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    String line = null;
    int val = 0;
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do{
        System.out.println("Usage: Enter votes. Enter -1 to exit");
        int voteNumber = 0; 
        while(voteNumber<5){ 
              try {
                line = is.readLine();
                val = Integer.parseInt(line);
                votes[voteNumber] = val;
                voteNumber++;
              } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println("Not a valid number: " + line);
                System.out.println("Usage: Enter votes. Enter -1 to exit");
              } 
        }
    }while(val != -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code You are creating an infinite loop.

Instead, you should write:

```
votecount = kybd.nextInt(); // in the Loop and At End..
```

gurung is right..