# scan the array input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array sorting input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455419/array-sorting-input)

> Implement a program to process votes for 5 candidates in a talent
>   contest.
>
> The program should use a String array to hold the names of the 5
>   candidates and an integer array to record the number of votes for each
>   contestant.
>
> It should prompt the user to enter the number of the candidate they
>   wish to vote for (in the range 0 – 4), until -1 is entered, which
>   signifies the end of voting. An error message should be output if the
>   candidate selected is not in the required range.
>
> At the end of voting, the program should sort the votes into
>   descending order and output them, before outputting messages showing
>   who was in 3rd, 2nd and 1st place

Well, so far I had some failures that's all. I will not have any problem with sorting and swapping the input. But the input itself is a pain for me.

```
//exam result processing - using selection sort

import java.util.*;

public class VoteCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create empty array
        int[] votes = new int[5];

        //input data
        input(votes);
    }

    public static void input(int[] votes) 
    {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
        int votecount = kybd.nextInt();

        while (votecount !=-1) 
        {
            votes[votecount]++;  
            System.out.println("Candidate" + votes +"Has" +votecount + "votes");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked the exact same question 30min ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455419/array-sorting-input

Comment: yes i did and no ansver so far thought. the question is a request with help in coding of input part of the code.

Comment: @JohnathanSmith Not getting an answer is NOT a reason to post the question again. You should never do that. Clarify your original question. Address comments. But don't simply post it again.

Comment: @JohnathanSmith Did you try the answer I posted on your previous question? It answers your issues of exiting when -1 is entered at the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kybd.hasNext()` to test whether there is any more vote number. and you can input in the terminal like this:
    `0,1,2,1,3`
and modify while() to:
    `while(kybd.hasNext())`

there is no need of `-1` to end input, and you have to input all vote number in one line. you can use `<space>`、comma or `<Tab>` to split vote numbers.

Comment: you see the problem is that i MUST to make the programm to stop by entering -1 and then giving me the full detail of the data enteret

Comment: ok, then have a try with @GETah's answer..

Answer (score 0):

you have to read the user's input inside the while cycle, like this:

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
int votecount = kybd.nextInt();

while (votecount !=-1) 
{
    votes[votecount]++;  
    System.out.println("Candidate "+names[votecount]+" Has "+votes[votecount]+" votes");
    System.out.println("Enter vote number of the candidate results: ");
    votecount = kybd.nextInt();
}
```

in additional, "votes" is an array, so printing in will give you something like "0@562fb45", so let's say you wil create some "names" array, which will hold the candidates names, like this for example:

```
String names = {"Peter", "Tomas", "Jonny", "Mark", "Jane"};
```